# Google Sheets - Rank of rows by date group by item

Tags: google-sheets

Original data

```
fruit    date
orange   01/01/2016
mango    02/02/2015
apple    03/03/2017
mango    02/02/2014
apple    03/03/2018
orange   01/01/2017
orange   01/01/2015
```

I would like to group them by fruit and has their rank order by date

Result would be like

```
fruit    date          rank
orange   01/01/2016      2
mango    02/02/2015      2
apple    03/03/2017      1
mango    02/02/2014      1
apple    03/03/2018      2
orange   01/01/2017      3
orange   01/01/2015      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fruit` is in A1 please try in say C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=countifs(A$2:A,A2,B$2:B,"<"&B2)+countifs(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)
```

{I appreciate your choosing unambiguous dates.}

Comment: Thanks, I tried using array and rank function, but no success, I was surprised that it can be solved using countifs :)